# Setter is not getting invoked ,Could anyone please help me understand the flow and how to get setter invoked?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, getter, setter, javascript-debugging

Html File

```
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Enter your First Name" onchange={captureFName}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Enter your Last Name" onchange={captureLName}></lightning-input>
    <div>Full Name is {fullName}</div>
</template>
```

JS file

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class ExploreSettersGetters extends LightningElement {

    _outputValue;
    fullName='default'
    fname;
    lname;

    captureFName(event) {
        this.fname = event.target.value;
    }

    captureLName(event) {
        this.lname = event.target.value;
        this._outputValue = this.fname +' '+ this.lname;
    }
    @api
    get fullName() {
        console.log('in getter')
        return this._outputValue;
    }
    set fullName(value) {
        console.log('in setter')
        if (this.fname && this.lname) {
            if (this.fname.length > 10) {
                try {
                    throw new Error('First name cannot be more than 10 characters');
                } catch (e) {
                    this.showToast('Error', e.message, 'Error')
                }

            }
            if (this.lname.length > 10) {
                try {
                    throw new Error('Last name cannot be more than 10 characters');
                } catch (e) {
                    this.showToast('Error', e.message, 'Error')
                }
            }
            
        }
        this._outputValue = value.toUpperCase();
    }
        showToast(tit, msg, vari) {
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: tit,
                message: msg,
                variant: vari,
                mode: 'dismissable'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to show full name in CAPS on UI, getter is called many times. When value fname, lname changes but setter is getting called only one at first time of loading component which is showing fullName value as DEFAULT.

What are changes that needs to be done for validation in setter to get work?

Note: If same validation is kept in getter it is throwing error but as per standards validation and logic needs to be handled in only setter

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you don't need custom code for input validation, you should leverage [`lightning-input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) attribute `max-length`:

> The maximum number of characters allowed in the field.
> Use this attribute with email, password, search, tel, text, and url input types only.

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Enter your First Name" onchange={captureFName} max-length="10"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Enter your Last Name" onchange={captureLName} max-length="10"></lightning-input>
    <div>Full Name is {fullName}</div>
</template>
```

This way users won't be able to input more than 10 characters.

Even if you want to do your own validation, you don't need to throw an error just to catch it the line after, you could simply show the toast message.

Finally you should not define the same instance variable multiple times: currently you defined `fullName` then created a getter and setter for the same variable. If you need the getter and setter, you should use only them.

[Setter documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) (emphasis mine)

> The `set` syntax binds an object property to a function to be called **when there is an attempt to set that property**

The setter is never called when you change the last name, because you never set `fullName`, you just set `_outputValue`.
In order to call the setter you should change `captureLName` method to

```js
captureLName(event) {
    this.lname = event.target.value;
    this.fullName = this.fname +' '+ this.lname;
}
```

You decorated the getter with [`@api`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_public), please note that if you don't need to expose that proprety (to make it public) you don't need the decorator.
In this case the JS code of the component could be:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ExploreSettersGetters extends LightningElement {

    firstName;
    lastName;

    captureFName(event) {
        this.firstName = event.target.value;
    }

    captureLName(event) {
        this.lastName = event.target.value;
    }

    get fullName() {
        console.log('in getter')
        return (this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName).toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

Comment: I know about max length attribute on ltng input tag but tried different way,Where you have used Setter, I want to understand how setter can be used

Comment: @sfdcgv if you declare just a getter, you're creating a read-only instance property, using a setter too the result is the same of declaring a standalone instance property. This means that you can access to that property via dot notation: `classInstance.property`, or if you're in the same class, as in LWC context, `this.property`. That's why to *use* the setter you must write `this.fullName = this.fname +' '+ this.lname;` instead of `this._outputValue = this.fname +' '+ this.lname;` and that's why you should not redeclare another property with the same name, the one initialized to `default`

Comment: Thanks Ruben it hepled

Answer (score 0):

Remove fullName='default'. If you need a default value when lwc is loaded, set the value in connectedCallback()

Comment: What is order in which setter and getter in called 
Will setter gets called first followed by getter ?